# mnist_with_summaries.py error: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

When I try to run mnist_with_summaries.py I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/rob/tf_from_source/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 110, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>     File "/home/rob/.virtualenvs/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
>       sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
>     File "/home/rob/tf_from_source/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 85, in main
>       writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir, sess.graph)
>     File "/home/rob/.virtualenvs/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py", line 104, in **init**
>       self.add_graph(graph_def)
>     File "/home/rob/.virtualenvs/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py", line 168, in add_graph
>       graph_bytes = graph_def.SerializeToString()
>   AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'

I'm also seeing this error on some of my own code when I try to generate a tensorboard graph. Any ideas about the problem and solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer was provided [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1690). I rolled back to the r0.7 branch and the problem was resolved.